# SOLR wildcard search for prefix

Tags: solr

I have some data in the following format:

```
2 QUEEN STREET
2 QUENTIN STREET
UNIT 1 2 QUEEN STREET
```

Currently, I can search using the following

```
street_name:/2[A-Z]* QUE[A-Z]*.*/)
```

and it I get

```
2 QUEEN STREET
2 QUENTIN STREET
```

Is there a way to include the 3rd name in the results rather than doing a separate query

```
street_name:/[0-9A-Z] 2[A-Z]* QUE[A-Z]*.*/)
```

which returns

```
UNIT 1 2 QUEEN STREET
```

Basically, looking to get all three results in one go.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here... figured out that I can use the OR operator to combine queries.